# What is an example of a three-terminal current-controlled voltage source?

Tags: voltage-source

Dependent sources come in four flavors:

- voltage-dependent current sources (e.g. a FET can act as a VCCS)
- current-dependent current sources (BJT)
- voltage-dependent voltage sources (OpAmp as an example of a linear component)
- current-dependent voltage sources

[A resistor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/107569/how-is-a-current-controlled-voltage-source-different-from-a-resistor) can be seen as a special type of CCVS, where the current through the resistor determines the voltage across it.

Is there such a thing as a three-terminal current-controlled voltage source? I guess the equivalent circuit could look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftp28hm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The current at AM1 controls the voltage across R1, measured by VM1. But is there a single, specific component that does the same thing?

Comment: I think your exercise is a pointless. Why? Because you try to find examples of devices which behave as **ideal devices**. The point of those ideal devices is that they are **not real**. We use them to **model** the behavior of **real** devices. *a FET can act as a VCCS* not really as a FET is very non-linear and has a finite output impedance, limited output current range etc. We can however **model** a FET, while it is operating under certain conditions, as a VCCS. Not the other way round.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie But does a VCCS need to be linear? I'm not looking for ideal devices, but rather for the 'missing component': in an FET, the current is controlled by a voltage. In a BJT, the current is controlled by a current. In an OpAmp, the voltage is controlled by a voltage. That leaves the last combination, which so far I have only seen as a conjunction of several other components. If such a device doesn't exist, doesn't have a special name or is generally never needed in applications, that would also be an answer.

Comment: All these can be made using opamps, including the CCVS: https://www.electronics-tutorial.net/analog-integrated-circuits/current-to-voltage-converter/index.html  So it is not a question of "can I make one?" Yes you can. All that's needed is an Opamp, some resistors and perhaps a MOSFET.

Comment: A Norton amplifier is kinda like a CCVS: https://mysite.du.edu/~etuttle/electron/elect21.htm

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thanks! My question though was if such device has a name and exists as a common lumped element, rather than 'if I can make one'. After all, I already showed a quick example in the question, so of course that's possible. To rephrase: does a component exist that directly controls the voltage through an applied current, rather than through the 'conversion' between current and voltage in a resistor?

Comment: If you're allowing "opamp" as a fundamental building block, then you can easily create all four configurations. And yes, they all use resistors to do the conversion between voltage and current.

Comment: Furthermore, your example is not really a voltage source anyway. It's really a current source in parallel with a resistor, which is equivalent to a voltage source in series with the same resistor. But it isn't anything anyone would consider a "pure voltage source".

Comment: @DaveTweed True, OpAmp is quite a stretch already. So basically such a component doesn't exist, got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much better and more practical implementation of a Current Controlled Voltage Source (CCVS) can be made using an Opamp:

[image]

[Source](https://www.electronics-tutorial.net/analog-integrated-circuits/current-to-voltage-converter/index.html)

All the other controlled sources can also be implemented using an opamp, some resistors and maybe a MOSFET (for the VCCS and CCCS).